# iOS - Label collision detection

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop, uilabel

I was wondering if anyone has had experience with dragging and dropping labels into a view and detecting if they collide or overlap. I was wondering how this can be done and also if they do collide/overlap that one of them is moved so its not overlapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UIKit Dynamics** is the way to go. Especially [UICollisionBehavior](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollisionBehavior_Class/Reference/Reference.html). You can use gesture recognizers for dragging views. I created a demo project that does exactly what you are asking about.

It's available here:

https://github.com/r3econ/Collision-Behavior-Demo

Comment: Dont think this will work. The labels get created dynamically, so its a sorting app so a word appears in the middle of the screen and its dragged into the appropriate view. So the issue is when I drag another label into the same view and have it overlap.

Comment: Ok, got it. You can use gesture recognizer for dragging and when the gesture ends check of the rectangles of the views intersect using `CGRectIntersectsRect` method.

Comment: I'd have to store all the placed labels and loop over that correct?

Comment: Yes, this would work. If you don't have hundreds of labels to loop over it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: any suggestion to how to find where there is empty space in the view?